# error MSB3073 on VS2010 post build step. exited with code -1073741512

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

i have a post build action to run an executable after a VS2010 build (a simple c++ project) is complete.. its building foo.exe and then running foo.exe as the post build step. When it runs, however, it displays this error:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code -1073741512.

i looked everywhere and i haven't found anything describing what this error code means.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: `-1073741512` in decimal translates `FFFFFFFFC0000138` in hex. Try searching for error code `0xC0000138`

Comment: *Never* run the program you build in a post-build step.  It is expected not to work on the first try.  Press F5 to use the debugger.  You've got a problem with a DLL.

Comment: Actually the project is a unit test project. This particular executable is a unit test executable that is unit testing the sw in another project in the solution..  we want it to be automatic as it should never fail.. Yes i dont know why i did't realize its decimal and should be converted to hex..  now i need to figure out what the dll issue is.. thanks!

Comment: ok i figured it out!  thanks!